# NLP: Language Analysis Techniques and Algorithms

Tags: nlp

**Situation:**

I wish to perform a Deep-level Analysis of a given text, which would mean:

1. Ability to extract keywords and assign importance levels based on contextual usage.
2. Ability to draw conclusions on the mood expressed.
3. Ability to hint on the education level (word does this a little bit though, but something more automated)
4. Ability to mix-and match phrases and find out certain communication patterns
5. Ability to draw substantial meaning out of it, so that it can be quantified and can be processed for answering by a machine.

**Question:**

What kind of algorithms and techniques need to be employed for this?

Is there a software that can help me in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you figure out how to do this please contact DARPA, the CIA, the FBI, and all other U.S. intelligence agencies.  Contracts for projects like these are items of current research worth many millions in research grants. ;)

That being said you'll need to process it in layers and analyze at each of those layers.  For items 2 and 3 you'll find training an SVM on n-tuples (try, 3) words will help.  For 1 and 4 you'll want deeper analysis.  Use a tool like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), or one of the many other parsers and find the subject words in sentences and related words.  Also use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) (from Princeton)
 to find the most common senses used and take those as key words.

5 is extremely challenging, I think intelligent use of the data above can give you what you want, but you'll need to use all your grammatical knowledge and programming knowledge, and it will still be *very* rough grained.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be open to some experimentation, in which case a toolkit approach might be best? If so, look at the NLTK Natural Language Toolkit for Python. Open source under the Apache license, and there are a couple of excellent books about it (including one from O'Reilly which is also released online under a creative commons license).

Comment: And as cpfohl says, what you are trying to do is difficult. With some domain constraints and experimentation you might be able to do something useful.

Comment: yep, I think so, that is is difficult. I somehow got the question into a very generalised form. The set of text for which I need is rather small and using any of these kits along with a bit of human intervention will do.

Comment: But then I thought about it and started considering this as a separate challenging problem albeit outside my current scope of study. It seems interesting and it also seems that there is a lot left to be done. :)